# app crashing after Importing Json file to nuxt app

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, nuxt.js

So I'm trying to import local JSON file to my nuxt app and display it but the size of the file is really big (400mb) and the app keeps crashing or the website won't load at all.

I already tried using another smaller JSON file and it worked perfectly.The memory used when loading the app went from 250mb to 4gb so i thought the problem would probably be because the JSON is too big.

Is there any way i can reduce it s size or make the app load the file ? (I've seen some similar issues that suggested lazy loading the component that imports the json but i'm not sure if that really can help)
Here's my import

```
<script>
import Repdata from "../report/report1.json"
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Rep: Repdata
    };

}}
</script>
```

Comment: reduce the size of JSON? Do you mean without losing data?

Comment: yeah or maybe load just the attributes im going to use

Comment: loading only the attributes you need would not be possible client side, since you can't parse JSON until the whole JSON is present - can it be done server side? Oh, wait ... you're obviously using some build tool here, since client (browser) code can't "import" json - I take it the json file is static in that case

Comment: yeah it is.It gets generated locally after a series of tests and now i'm trying to display the json file on my app.(Most of the json is base64 images idk if that can help)

Comment: How do you "compile" your vue app? you use webpack? Vite? something else?

Comment: I just use the nuxt default compilation and the rendering is client sided (I'm new to vue dev sorry if this does not answer your question)

Comment: Sorry, I think my comments regarding the build tool are only confusing the issue